# How to start app in Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

how to start Rails3 app? In last versions it was "ruby script/server", but how to do same thing in Rails3?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The new command is:

```
rails server
```

or

```
rails s
```

for short.

Answer (score 2):

I believe its `rails server` .

Answer (score 1):

Use the following commands: `rails server` or simply `rails s`

Answer (score 0):

From the app root directory:

`script/rails server`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bundler which is default now... you must use

`bundle exec rails server`

`bundle exec rails s` will also work!